# Why was the ISS' DC vacuum cleaner replaced with an AC version? Are there "wall sockets" throughout the ISS where it's plugged in?

Tags: iss, power, electronics

The question [Why did Apollo spacecraft use both AC and DC equipment? Still used in present and future designs?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22090/12102) and especially the answer there reminded me of something I'd seen in the YouTube video [One of the Most Detailed ISS Tour](https://youtu.be/QvTmdIhYnes) which also accompanied the question [How do iPads on the ISS know which way is “up” for their users?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21493/12102).

At about `03:40` in the video, astronaut [Steven Swanson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Swanson) introduces with a bit of humor the stowed, and presumably new, *AC version* of the vacuum cleaner used on the ISS:

> We do have one of the most important pieces of equipment on the International Space Station hidden up here. This is the vacuum cleaner, and it’s the AC version. And we say in NASA-talk that this is the only piece of equipment that *doesn’t suck* on the International Space Station. But this is actually much better than the old one, so we actually like it, and it’s nothing too fancy, just a vacuum cleaner, and we have to use it every week to keep the place clean.

Was there an earlier DC version of the vacuum cleaner? If so, what is the reason for the "upgrade"?

I'm also curious, are there standard type A or B wall sockets distributed around the ISS to plug things in to 120 VAC?

[image: AC vacuum cleaner on International Space Station]

[image: type A plug] [image: type B plug]

**above:** Type A & B wall sockets. (am I the only one experiencing mild [Pareidolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia) here?)

Comment: The old one didn't ride as well. https://www.cnet.com/news/iss-space-station-cosmonaut-vacuum-cleaner-anton-shkaplerov/

Comment: I wonder if they had a requirement that any DC motors be brush-less.

Comment: @amI that's an interesting question! Considering the number of motors on the ISS used in pumps, fans, actuators and [robots](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/22039/12102) there may indeed be rules against brushed motors. Why not ask that as a new question?

Comment: About your experience of pareidolia… You’re not the only one… Hydro-Québec, the electrical power company of the Canadian province, even had an ad running for a while where the electric sockets were animated characters.

Comment: @PierrePaquette that sounds absolutely frightening. **update:** I'm sitting in a library at this moment and you've made me laugh out loud! Curse you, YouTube! :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Boiling this down to

> 1a) Was there an earlier DC version of the ISS' DC vacuum cleaner ...
>
> 1b) ... if so why was it replaced with an AC version?
>
> 2a) Are there “wall sockets” throughout the ISS where it's plugged
> in...
>
> 2b) ... if so, what are they like?

I can answer some of these.

1a) Yes, there was an earlier DC version of the ISS vacuum cleaner.

It looked like this...

[image]

And ran off of 120 VDC. It was a wet/dry vacuum, and included a hair clipper attachment.

The very best thing about this information source is that it tells us the contact person for the vacuum is named "Bum Jacinto".

[Source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&ved=2ahUKEwi6sc-Rz8DdAhUNP6wKHW4JClcQFjAMegQIBRAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Feveryspec.com%2FNASA%2FNASA-JSC%2FNASA-JSC-PUBS%2Fdownload.php%3Fspec%3DJSC-28533E.029700.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0Ac9-j6rDQByxq4ujKVUTh): JSC-28533 INTERNATIONAL SPACE STATION
CATALOGUE
OF
INTRAVEHICULAR ACTIVITY
(IVA)
GOVERNMENT FURNISHED EQUIPMENT
(GFE)
FLIGHT CREW EQUIPMENT
(FCE) .

2a) Are there “wall sockets” throughout the ISS where it's plugged in...

Yes.

2b) ... if so, what are they like?

The DC power outlets in the US side of the ISS are < start rant> overly complicated like everything in the ISS and are < end rant> called Utility Outlet Panels, they look like this. The actual "sockets" receive cannon plugs and are behind the two gray threaded caps secured by wires.

[image]

[Source](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20160014034.pdf)

AC is provided by inverter boxes made by [Exeltech](https://exeltech.com/about-exeltech/project-gallery/).

[image]

However, all that being said, there is one of your questions I cannot answer, and that is *why* the vacuum cleaner was upgraded.

Unless that is, as I said in a comment, because it rides well.

[image]

[Link to video](https://www.slavorum.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/mksvaccuum.mp4?_=1).

Comment: We have data on "rides better" and that's good enough for me, so let's call this *answered* until such time that we decide to revive Edison and Tesla and let them re-litigate DC vs AC. Thanks for the research!

Comment: @uhoh all these years later I realized I had mixed up 120 V AC and DC in this answer. Profuse apologies.

Comment: We can only hope that no vacuum cleaners blew up on the ISS because they were using Space SE as a reference! Fond farewell to the Gilda Radner reference :-)

Comment: @uhoh especially mortifying because it says *VDC right on the device faceplate* facepalm

Comment: The link has rotten away, but you can still find the video in a [tweet by Anton Shkaplerov](https://twitter.com/Anton_Astrey/status/954717727540830208)