# Are all DC motors on the inside of the ISS brushless?

Tags: iss, electronics, robotics, equipment

Considering the number of motors on the ISS used in pumps, fans, actuators and robots, are there rules against brushed motors, motors with electrical brushes which can make particulate matter?

Based on @amI's [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27531/why-was-the-iss-dc-vacuum-cleaner-replaced-with-an-ac-version-are-there-wall#comment109367_27531):

> I wonder if they had a requirement that any DC motors be brush-less.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  According to page 221 of NASA's 1998 report TM-98-206956/VOL1, [Living Together in Space: The Design and Operation
of the Life Support Systems on the International
Space Station](https://spacecraft.ssl.umd.edu/academics/697S09/docs/NASA-TM-98-206956.pdf) (page 255 of the pdf file),

> a 28 Vdc brush-type motor ... 14.85 W peak

drives the relief valve of ISS's Positive Pressure Relief Assembly (PPRA).

Comment: You found the black swan! Congrats.