# Is there dust on ISS and how do they do cleaning?

Tags: iss, dust

Where are humans there is normally dust. It likes any more or less electrostatic surface.

Is there dust at ISS and do they clean it beyond using air filters in the air system?

Comment: They use a vaccuum cleaner.  [Anton Shkaplerov](https://www.rt.com/news/416552-cosmonaut-vacuum-space-iss/) famously flew one on the ISS

Comment: Living humans are a constant source of dander, on Earth and in orbit. So there is dust in ISS and there is a vaccuum cleaner.

Comment: [Why was the ISS' DC vacuum cleaner replaced with an AC version? Are there “wall sockets” throughout the ISS where it's plugged in?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27531/12102)

Comment: I don't have enough for an answer, but oh my yes.  I've seen pictures of the air filters in the crew quarters, and they get *nasty*.